# Read file with BufferReader when multiple thread writing to the file

Tags: java, multithreading, file, thread-safety

All, I am trying to read a file which will be written by multiple threads, I am going to use `BufferedReader` to read that file in a thread.

The code looks like below.

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
String detail;
while ((detail =br.readLine()) != null)
{
   ...
}
```

Currently It seems works fine. But I have some questions about it.
If the question sound silly. please don't laugh at me . thanks.

Is it possible that the loop never been broken ? because the other threads are writing into the file.So maybe the `readLine()` may never return null?

**Updated**

Let's say there are 3 threads(T1,T2,T3).

T1 and T2 are writer.

T3 is reader.

The code runs in below sequence.

1.The current file lines number is 100.

2.T1 write a line to file.(file lines increase to 101)

3.T3 reads the last line of file(101). next read will get null.

4.T2 append a line to file.(file lines increase to 102)

5.T3 read again....(Does it return null or not? because T2 just added a new line into file before T3 read again.)

Please help to review it .thanks in advance.

Comment: If the reader is reading faster than the writers are writing, eventually it will arrive to the end of the file and then it will return null. If not, then it will finish when your filesystem runs out of free space and the writers stop with an IOException

Comment: @Pablo I am just not sure if the case I said could happen. It sound like race issue? thanks

Comment: To simulate the scenario, you can set the thread priority or sleep time

Comment: Are all these threads in the same JVM? If so, why use the clumsy and error-prone file approach instead of something like a concurrent queue?

Comment: @chrylis Yes. They are. In my design. The file is a log file generated by Log4j. I need inspect the file line by line to search the specified content.

Comment: @Pablo Yes , It could happen.

Comment: It seems it would be simpler to write your own logger implementation.

Comment: @chrylis Sounds good idea +1. What should I do with this custom logger?How to implement it ? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that the loop will never end (at least until you run out of memory). Here's some code to prove it:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// start thread to write to file
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FileWriter writer;
                try {
                    int i = 1;
                    writer = new FileWriter("D:\\text.txt");
                    writer.append("line"+ i++ + "\n");
                    writer.flush();
                    while (true)
                    {
                        writer.append("line"+ i++ + "\n");
                        writer.flush();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // start thread to read file
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FileReader reader = new FileReader("D:\\text.txt");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    String detail;
                    while ((detail =br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(detail);
                    }
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Right , I also did some test like you. It could happen. (never end.)

Answer (score 0):

I did some experiment for it .

One eclipse run a program as writer .

```
public class Main {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        log.warn("Test test test  ");
    }
}
```

Another eclipse run the program as reader.

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        StringBuffer intiLine = new StringBuffer("");
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("D:\\logs\\notify-subscription.log");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String detail;
        while ((detail =br.readLine()) != null)//debug and set breakpoint here
        {
            System.out.println(detail);
        }
    }
}
```

before I began to test them. The original log file content is empty.
I ran the reader program at first. the result of `br.readLine()` supposed to be null. But I set break point at the code line `while ((detail =br.readLine()) != null)` run, before it run , I ran the writer program. So the file contains `test test test`. and `br.readLine()` will not be null.

Answer (score -1):

You are absolutely Correct .There will be  a chance for Deadlock also if you keep creating threads for writing content to the file.Because if threads are keep on writing to the file there wont be any chance of exiting from loop it goes to infinite state

Comment: But disk space is not infinite, writers cannot write forever

Comment: An infinite loop is not a deadlock.

Comment: Yes. you are correct.But i believe it may effects on request time out scenarios @Pablo